# Product Keys optimization

Tags: security, language-agnostic, cryptography, license-key

I am seeking advice on the following:

Keeping a list of what product key belongs to which client. For example, if i was issued with product key 8456-7894-4567-7894 This should be design in such a way that it would be easy to write the list to a database instead of a file.

How to  keep record of them in a file.

If i want to migrate to a database in future and do not want to redo everything.

Thanks,

Comment: This looks like a requirement that was copied and pasted... Does your requirements document says that you should be able to edit the file manually, with "business" tools like Notepad or Excel for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your choice of platform has bindings for [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), you'll definitely want to look into it - it's probably the easiest way to do what you're looking for.

SQLite databases fit neatly into single files and are surprisingly easy to create if you know a bit of SQL. Additionally, code written for use with SQLite is not difficult to adapt for use with more heavyweight database engines.

You'll probably want to create a table of user data, and another table of valid product keys and their assigned users.